# Adding description text to attribute field using attribute table in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I'm using QGIS 3.0.1 and I would like to add a description text to an attribute field. I already use the alias text but I am interested in to store a more detailed description text for an attribute field like a tooltip or something similar. I know how to define conditional formatting (in qgis and python) but I'm not sure if it is possible to add this "detailed" information.

Should this not be possible, could I use customized signals? I mean, when I press F1 something happens (e.g. I create a pop up with my description).

With respect to my problem, I try to implement my own shortcut function using "QShortcut". This works but now I need the index of the selected field, similar to signal "attributeValueChanged". With this information I could create my own pop up with related description.

Should this not be possible, I would create a dialog including a combo box where the user can select one of the fields of the layer. After that the related description would be displayed.

Answer (score 2):

When you add a new a field from the attribute table, you can add a **comment** to that field.

[image]

You can view the comment in the layer properties...

[image]

...and by mousing over the field name in the edit feature form.

[image]

Note: There are probably other ways to use the field comment feature, but I couldn't find any documentation. Basically every website has a comment section, so "comment" is useless as a search term.

There's no way to add comment text to an existing field (at least not that I could find, but see the note above). A workaround would be to create a new field with the desired comment. Then fill the new field with values from the old field, and delete the old field.

Tested adding a field with a comment with the following file types:

- shapefile - comment initially appears in layer properties but disappears after saving the layer edits
- geopackage - same as shapefile
- temporary scratch layer - comment persists after saving layer edits (but this type of layer is deleted upon closing the QGIS project)

Comment: I tried the same but could it be that the comment function does not work for vector layers? I added the comment like you did but I don't see the comment in the attribute table layout. After reloading my shape file, my comment does not exist. The shape file was saved before. Take a look at my screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/PyISEOK.png

Comment: I tested this first only on a temporary scratch layer. After testing on shapefile and geopackage, I see that the comments aren't saved. So, this doesn't solve your problem. Sorry. :(

Comment: At least thank you for your efforts. :) Now I'm using a QInputDialog and I am satisfied with the solution.